# FQL (multi)query not with legacy REST but with Graph API not working on Insights?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to send FQL multiqueries as described [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) without using old legacy REST API but with Graph.

This is an old request with Graffiti application:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20metric%2C%20value%20FROM%20insights%20WHERE%20object_id%3D2439131959%20AND%20metric%3D'application_active_users'%20AND%20end_time%3Dend_time_date('2011-06-26')%20AND%20period%3Dperiod('month')&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBACjLou2bh6PRtdhHuYqqQLrZAoXzBZAWVkH0QF9Lw3cqcviZAZCH1fwsqlagtwuCSjmA4gPPuftwWVGEuiMVnw7ab38aZCpfsR1LkbSqP
```

And result is (works):

```
<fql_query_response xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" list="true">
<insights>
<metric>
application_active_users
</metric>
<value>
955848
</value>
</insights>
</fql_query_response>
```

If understand it correctly it should work (slightly) modified as (single FQL):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20metric%2C%20value%20FROM%20insights%20WHERE%20object_id%3D2439131959%20AND%20metric%3D'application_active_users'%20AND%20end_time%3Dend_time_date('2011-06-26')%20AND%20period%3Dperiod('month')&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBACjLou2bh6PRtdhHuYqqQLrZAoXzBZAWVkH0QF9Lw3cqcviZAZCH1fwsqlagtwuCSjmA4gPPuftwWVGEuiMVnw7ab38aZCpfsR1LkbSqP
```

or even FQL multiquery:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q={"query1":"SELECT%20metric%2C%20value%20FROM%20insights%20WHERE%20object_id%3D2439131959%20AND%20metric%3D'application_active_users'%20AND%20end_time%3Dend_time_date('2011-06-26')%20AND%20period%3Dperiod('month')&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBACjLou2bh6PRtdhHuYqqQLrZAoXzBZAWVkH0QF9Lw3cqcviZAZCH1fwsqlagtwuCSjmA4gPPuftwWVGEuiMVnw7ab38aZCpfsR1LkbSqP"}
```

and result is **empty**, no errors, in both cases. For me: (multi) FQL queries work for **user**, not for the page. Graph insights works fine for the same page.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to myself: it works using timestamps as `end_date` (that is not using `end_time_date` function) and with `period` function. Don't know why.

Comment: I still have trouble with the FQL and Insights. Could you be so kind to write down an example of a whole, single query to insights. Should there for example be an accesstoken in the end or not? I've seen both...

Answer (score 0):

REST API is deprecated I know or will be completely deprecated in June. That is why we have some non-empty insights for some metrics I think.But I have empty insights too with

https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT...

For me I think this "end_time_date" function is not clearly defined in the API or there could be a bug in FB API. Because when I write a unix time instead of this func it works fine sometimes